# Example of a sequence with integral → 0 but gn(x) does not converge to zero and >=0.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I need to think of an example of a sequence $g_n$ with $\int_0^1g_n → 0 $ but $g_n(x)$ does not converge to zero for any $x∈ [0,1]$ and $g_n(x) ≥ 0$ for all $x$ and $n$.

Hints and help wanted!

The fact $g_n(x)$ does not converge to zero is what has caused most of my attempts to fail.

Comment: All you need is for the measure of the set on which $g_n$ is not zero to go to zero. In order for this to happen but $g_n(x)\nrightarrow 0$ for any $x$, you can just let the set on which $g_n$ is non-zero hop around a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just let $\{g_n\}$ be a sequence of indicator functions on the sets:

$$\left\{\left[0,1\right],\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right],\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right], \left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right],\left[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right],\left[\frac{2}{3},1\right],\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right],..\right\}.$$

Do you see why this works?

Answer (score 0):

For any $n$, let $k$ and $m$ such that $2^m\le n<2^{m+1}$ and $n=2^m+k$. Hence $0\le k<2^m\le n$

Then, let $g_n(x)=1$ iff $x\in[\frac{k}{2^m},\frac{k+1}{2^m}]$, $g_n(x)=0$ otherwise.

Note that $\int_0^1g_n(x)=2^{-m}\rightarrow 0$, but for any $x$, $g_n(x)$ will alternate infinitely often between $0$ and $1$.